# Add static cms block in home page

Tags: cms, static-block

I have read different tuts about this and some say it all can be done from the admin panel, others say I have to add code in my layout and in the template files. Well, nothing works...

1. I created the static block from *admin > CMS > static blocks* with identifier **home_image-center**
2. Found the template *app/design/frontend/enterprise/my_theme/template/cms/home.phtml* and in the place where I want the block to stand I wrote this code:

   `<div>`

   `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home_image-center')->toHtml();?>`

   `</div>`
3. In *admin > CMS > Pages* opened the page called `home` and in the *Design* tab in *Custom Layout Update XML* field I added this code: `<block type="core/template" name="home_image-center" template="cms/home.phtml" />` between the `reference` tags.

I have put some text in the content of the static block, just to see whether it will be shown, but it's not. My final aim is to put that block there and make it available to have a static image or text in it, that can be changed at any time from the back-end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right, so I (and you guys) were very close.
In the current CMS page in *Design > Custom design > Custom Layout Update XML* field I had to put

```
<block type="cms/block" name="home_center-image" before="-">
      <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>home_center-image</block_id></action>
</block>
```

and before I tried just `<block type="core/template" name="home_image-center" template="cms/home.phtml" />`.

Now it is working fine. :)

Comment: You can also add static block in content area like this : `{{block type="cms/block" block_id="home_image-center"}`

Answer (score 28):

I may be totally wrong, but you can call it like this

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="home_image-center"}}
```

in cms -> homepage-> content : in that click show/hideeditor 
 past above code it's work

Comment: I tried both your suggenstion and `{{block type="cms/block" block_id="home_center_image" template="cms/content.phtml"}}`... and it is not working.

Comment: you are writing block and template both are not work you can call differently it will work like call template file {{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/form-top.phtml"}}after call like block {{block type="cms/block" block_id="home_image-center"}}

Comment: welcome kalpesh :)

Comment: Starting with Magento Comunity 1.9.2.2 (or Enterprise Edition 1.14.2.2) you have to make sure that cms/block is allowed in System => Permissions => Blocks You can read more on http://www.dudesquare.nl/blog/2015/10/31/static-block-shortcodes-not-working-1-9-2-2/

Comment: This way works too if you add `cms/block` into System -> Permisions -> Blocks

Answer (score 13):

It is a late reply, but i will share. 
It is true that you can do it all from admin. You can add any static block to any cms page directly from admin as a widget. 
Open the CMS page and then click on content tab. At top click on Insert Widget... button. You will have the following window.

[image]

In the drop down, select CMS Static Block. Then you will have the following window.

[image]

Now, select any custom template, else keep it default and click on Select Block... button. In another pop up, you will have the complete list of hte blocks as below.

[image]

Select your desired block and the window will close. Now on insert widget window, click on insert widget, and the cms block will be added to your cms page.

It will insert the code, which will be like below:

```
{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="46"}}
```

I am using this same way to add cms static blocks to my cms pages and it works fine.

Thank you

Comment: Works like a charm

Answer (score 4):

```
 {{block type="cms/block" block_id="home_image-center"}}
```

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-create-and-edit-static-blocks

Answer (score 2):

you can add static cms block in home page in following way :

```
 adding static cms block in magento 1.x :
     {{block type="cms/block" block_id="identifier_of_your_block"}}

 adding static cms block in magento 2.x :
     {{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="identifier_of_your_block"}}
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check out the following:

`CMS` → `Pages`

Then look for the line-item which has *home* as the value under `URL Key` - click the row to start editing it.

On your left-hand-side options menu, click the `Contents` tab, then click `Show / Hide Editor` to view the contents of the page in raw code.

You can edit the page from here & make the changes which you desire.

**P.S.** This is a bit of a tricky one seeing as the changes could - as you mentioned - be required to be made directly in the template file. But from my experience, this method usually works 100%.

Comment: I tried that one also. I even put just text, in the content, to test, but the text was not shown... That makes my think it is not the correct CMS page I am writing in. But I want to change the home page, and this is the only CMS page which has the word `home` in its name...

Comment: Are you using a third party theme?